# Watson Assistant Dynamic Array(Context Variable)

Tags: expression, ibm-cloud, ibm-watson, watson-assistant

The Chatbot is detecting Law's(family law, contract law etc.)using a single entity with 200 plus values(Law's) Based on user response using this:

```
<?@All_Foci.values?>
```

E.g.
A user says I have problem in my contract's help me ?, chatbot detects law's using entity **@Focus** and than are saved in an array **$Detected_Foci**

I want to show user the **$Detected_Foci** dynamic values in the **option response type**.

```
 $Detected_Foci ["Sales contract law", "Contract law"]
```

How can I do that kindly help ?

Answer (score 1):

See here for an [example of how to convert an array to a string output](https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/assistant?topic=assistant-dialog-methods#dialog-methods-indirect-type-conversion).

```
{
  "context": {
    "detected_foci": [
      "contract law",
      "family law"
    ],
    "array_in_string": "this is what I have: $detected_foci"
  }
}
```

You could also directly refer to **detected_foci** in your response:

```
Here is what I have: <? $detected_foci ?>
```